# Constant meaning in java

Tags: java, spring, compiler-errors, static, constants

Currently, I am developing a spring-boot application and one of the rest controllers looks as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = VALUE)
public class SomeControllerClass {

  public final static String VALUE = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  
  ...

}
```

While developing this, I have encountered this issue when setting VALUE for `@RequestMapping`

> Attribute value must be constant

However, if I alter the static field assignment as it's presented below everything works fine:

```
public final static String VALUE = "someValue";
```

Now, I am wondering what are the differences (in terms of **java constant** meaning) between:

```
public final static String VALUE = "someValue";
```

and
public final static String VALUE = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

Comment: Well, what you need here is a compile time constant and `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` clearly doesn't satisfy this requirement.

Comment: It needs to be a compile time constant, not a runtime constant.

Comment: Your value may be changeable which not fulfilled the requirements of a final static value..

Comment: @AbdulKayuem how could it be possible to change? VALUE is a `final` field

Comment: Annotation values must be a _compile-time constant_. You initialize the field with multiple method calls that can (and in your case _will_) result in a different value every time the class is initialized. That won't work for annotations, as their values are determined at compile-time, not run-time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the formal definition of a constant is section 15.29 (*Constant Expressions*) in the Java Language Specification:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29

So, in the case of String constants, it's literal strings and any simple expression that uses other constant String variables.